# Which version of Python do I have installed?

Tags: python, compiling, geany

I'm trying to write a simple `Python` script using `Geany`. This IDE will automatically compile the code I write but I'm not sure which version of `Python` it is using. If I enter `python --version` in the command line I get:

```
Python 2.7.3
```

but if I enter `python3` I get:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 19:53:16) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Does Ubuntu come with both versions? If so, which one is `Geany` using to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with both versions, yes. The `python` command will *always* point to a Python 2.x version, and `python3` will always point to the default Python 3.x version. The `python` command will *never* point to Python 3.x.

I'm not sure what Geany uses exactly, but I would suspect it uses Python 2.x (and thus probably puts `#!/usr/bin/python` (or should put if it uses `/usr/bin/env python` instead), in the scripts it generates.

Answer (score 3):

Try running `import sys;print(sys.version_info)` from inside geany.

Comment: I get `sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)` so I guess it's using `python 2.7.3`.

Comment: @Gabriel Indeed, also, you should mark either my answer or dobey's as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

To find out what version of python you are running.

Of course due to changes in python 3 `print` is now a function so this won't work for version 3.  In that case you would use:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```